# jquery flexigrid set active row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, flexigrid

How do I set a active row in jQuery Flexigrid after reloading it (after a ajax callback)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the following when onSuccess is fired...

`$("#rowID").click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#row1").addClass("trSelected");
```